# Wicket csv export

Tags: csv, export, wicket

Using wicket 6 and jersey

I have a datatable which contains a subset of data, sadly when the user does a data export they want the full set of data so i have created a restservice that returns a csv file when called.

My issue is the form of the url will change depending on the model of the form that is used to populate the datatable.

I have looked at ExternaLink, ResourceLink but with no luck, any ideas how to achieve this ?

Additionally i really don't want to have to create the file on the server side, i have been trying to get it streamed to the browser which is currently happening if i call the rest service directly through a browser

Answer (score 1):

Use a button or Link (could be ajax too) and redirect to your rest service:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+redirect+to+an+external+non-Wicket+page

```
public void onSubmit()
{
    getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new RedirectRequestTarget("/path/to/service/" + createServiceParams()));
}
```

For Wicket 6 the following should do it:

```
    throw new RedirectToUrlException("/path/to/service/" + createServiceParams()));
```

Comment: i believe this is only applicable for wicket 1.5 though. I think wicket 6 does not have setRequestTarget

Comment: I will give this a go but unsure if throwing an exception for expected program flow is the way to go, i guess i need to do some further reading on this but if it works I will accept the answer. Thankyou for your time.